# Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.example.app.Dblogic) [Instantiatable]

Tags: java, android, sqlite, constructor

I am currently using Android studio 1.1.0.

My project builds successfully. however, when i try to create signed APK, I see the following message:
Error:Error: This class should provide a default constructor (a public constructor with no arguments) (com.example.app.Dblogic) [Instantiatable]

I have seen many folks suggesting me to create an empty constructor.
However, my class Dblogic extends SQLiteOpenHelper.
When i create and empty constructor for Dblogic, i see the message:
there is no default constructor available in android.database.sqlite.sqliteopenhelper

It seems like a catch-22 situation.
Appreciate your help!

Code:

```
package com.example.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class Dblogic extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sweet.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

static final String TABLE_NAME1 = "tb_sweet";

private SQLiteDatabase database;

public Dblogic() {
}


public Dblogic(Context context) {
//public Dblogic() {
    //super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}



@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME1    + " ( "    + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Date TEXT NOT NULL, Name TEXT NOT NULL, Description TEXT NOT NULL, Image BLOB);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME1);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void openDB() throws SQLException {
    database = getWritableDatabase();
}

public void closeDB() {
    database.close();
}

public long insertQuery(ContentValues cValues) {
    return database.insert(TABLE_NAME1, null, cValues);
}
```

}

Comment: base class doesn't have no-arg constructor!! you can call your parameterized constructor from your no-arg constructor using this reference.

Comment: Could you please provide sample code? my Initial code did not have the following: public Dblogic() {}. when i tried to sign the APK, it suggested that I add empty constructor. That is when i added it. Thanks!

Comment: `public Dblogic() { this.Dblogic(new Context());}` it can be as this. you can write some thing like this

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code for context, I see that "Context is abstract and cannot be instantiated". And for constructor method I see "there is no default constructor available in android.database.sqlite.sqliteopenhelper".

Comment: `public Dblogic() { this.Dblogic(null);}` you can simply try this.

Comment: Context problem is solved. Thanks!. Still I get error for constructor method "there is no default constructor available in android.database.sqlite.sqliteopenhelper".

Comment: then there might be some different issue in your app. because initially it should not throw any exception when you don't have any no-arg constructor. but if you written and you are calling any other constructor then also it should not check base class constructor (default).

Comment: You are treating the symptoms and not the root cause. Have you accidentally declared the class as an entry point in manifest?

Answer (score -2):

```
public Dblogic() {

    super(null, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

I had the same problem and could solve it by the above code.

Comment: Answers in english please.